# Use arrow key input for SceneKit game in Swift

Tags: swift, scenekit, nsevent

I am trying to create a swift file that will detect keyboard input from MacOS for a SceneKit game in swift. I am using the NSEvent to handle key events but I keep getting the error 'use of undeclared type NSEvent. Is there an easier way to achieve this?

I have tried the following code:

```
override func keyDown(event: NSEvent) {
    interpretKeyEvents([event]) // calls insertText(_:), moveUp(_:), etc.
}

override func insertText(insertString: AnyObject) {
    let str = insertString as! String
    switch str {
    case " ":
        println("User hit the spacebar.")
    default:
        println("Unrecognized input: \(str)")
    }
}

override func moveUp(sender: AnyObject?) {
    println("Up arrow.")
}

override func moveLeft(sender: AnyObject?) {
    println("Left arrow.")
}

override func deleteBackward(sender: AnyObject?) {
    println("Delete.")
}
```

Comment: do you `import Cocoa` ?

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let keyCode = theEvent.keyCode if(keyCode == 123)//Left{
    }
    if(keyCode == 124)//Right
    {
    }
    if(keyCode == 125)//Down
    {
    }
    if(keyCode == 126)//Up
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an update (2020) to a QA asked in (2015).

```
override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
guard let key = presses.first?.key else { return }

switch key.keyCode {
case .keyboardR:
    print("Roll dice")
case .keyboardH:
    print("Show help")
default:
    super.pressesBegan(presses, with: event)
}
```

}